# Heb 6.18 says there are two immutable things; why can't there be three immutable things (according to Gen 15, the covenant with Abram)?

Tags: genesis, textual-criticism, jeremiah, abraham, metaphor

God cannot deny His promise nor His oath. These are two immutable things, says Heb 6.18. But covenant too is the third one which God cannot deny. If He denies, he will become like Jer 34:18.

So by *three* immutable things, in which it is impossible for God to lie, we might have strong consolation, who have fled for refuge to lay hold of the hope set before us.

For these three reasons (promise, sworn on, covenant) Abraham did not become sluggish but with patience and *courage*, inherited the promise.

Comment: His promise and covenant are basically same. It is unnecessary to add another thing. The verse doesn't mean there are only 2 things in which God can't lie, but simply 2 immutable things not just one, in which our faith is strengthened. Remember to quote the version with block quote in the question.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics.  We are different to other sites, and this link will explain how, and what we look for in questions and answers: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: The purpose of the site is not to write scripture, nor to re-write scripture. The purpose of the site is to _hermeneutically_ examine the _text_ of scripture.

Answer (score 4):

I am struggling to grasp what you mean by suggesting there should be three immutable (or unchangeable) things by which Abraham could have hope in God’s promise to him.

Context is everything, and Hebrews 6:13-20 is all about the covenant promise God made to Abraham.  The two unchangeable elements of God’s covenant promise to Abraham are the promise itself and the oath by which he swore it.

***The covenant is the object of God’s promise and God’s sworn oath.***  As Hebrews 11:13-16 points out:

> All these people were still living by faith when they died.  They did not receive the things promised; they only saw them and welcomed them from a distance.  And they admitted that they were aliens and strangers on earth. People who say such things show that they are looking for a country of their own.  If they had been thinking of the country they had left, they would have had opportunity to return.  Instead, they were longing for a better country – a heavenly one.  Therefore God is not ashamed to be called their God, for he has prepared a city for them.

God promised that the number of Abraham’s children would rival that of “the dust of the earth” (Genesis 15:16). Nations and kings would proceed from him (Genesis 17:6). It is significant that the promise was given to an aged, childless couple. But Abraham “did not waver through unbelief” (Romans 4:20), and his wife Sarah “considered him faithful who had made the promise” (Hebrews 11:11). Abraham was justified by his faith (Genesis 15:6), and he and his wife welcomed Isaac, the son of promise, into their home when they were 100 and 90 years old, respectively (Genesis 21:5).

The Abrahamic Covenant also included a promise of blessing and redemption (Genesis 12:3). All the earth would be blessed through Abraham. This promise finds its fulfillment in the New Covenant (Jeremiah 31:31–34; cf. Luke 22:20), which was ratified by Jesus Christ, the son of Abraham and Redeemer who will one day “restore everything” (Acts 3:21).

Five times in Genesis 12, as God is giving the Abrahamic Covenant, He says, “I will.”  ***The Abrahamic covenant is unconditional.   God’s promise and his name are the two immutable, or unchangeable, things by which his covenant stands.***

Comment: I fully agree - the promise is the covenant.

Answer (score 1):

A covenant isn't a third thing.

A covenant is simply a specific example of a formal agreement that someone commits to.

To break such an agreement would be to break one's word, to deny one's promise or oath.

Comment: Fully agree - the promise is the covenant!